# Тернарный оператор

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Какая функция быстрее работает?

```
template <typename T> T abs(T n) {return n<0 ? -n : n;}
```

или

```
template <typename T> T abs(T n) {return n*(n<0 ? -1 : 1);}
```

Comment: А самому проверить сложно?

Comment: @VladD как?????

Comment: @VladD обясните я б не спрашивал если б знал как

Comment: Ну, берёте тестовую программу, вызываете один из них с разными аргументами миллион раз, измеряете время пробега. То же с другим вариантом. Сравниваете.

Answer (score 12):

Прежде чем ответить, отдельно замечу, что вам **эта информация ничем не поможет**. Почему?

- Это шаблон. Он будет инстанцирован для каждого типа отдельно, поэтому результат сильно зависит от типа (код может и вовсе не скомпилироваться с некоторыми типами). Хотите сравнивать -- скажите, какой тип вас интересует. А я поведу себя, как С, и предположу `int`.
- `abs` есть в стандартной библиотеке, и есть основания думать, что он максимально эффективен.
- Это микрооптимизация, эффект от которой на общем времени программы вы вряд ли заметите. Скажем так -- время, которое вы этим сэкономите, скорее всего, в сумме по всем пользователям за всё время существования вашей программы не превысит даже то время, что я писал этот ответ. `:)`

Но давайте [проверим](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22C4TwDgpgJhBmAEBLAdseAVA3AKHfAhgEYDOAFHsgJTwDeAThMAK53LzIA8ADPAPzwBaNgC52mAL7ZcBEgCZy7avUYs2yAFSlOPfgICM8UXsoSgAA%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g530%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O3%22%7D%5D%7D) с `int`:

```
typedef int T;
T abs(T n) {return n<0 ? -n : n;}

T abs2(T n) {return n*(n<0 ? -1 : 1);}
```

Результат на x86 GCC 5.3.0 с флагом `-O3`:

```
abs(int):
        movl    %edi, %edx
        movl    %edi, %eax
        sarl    $31, %edx
        xorl    %edx, %eax
        subl    %edx, %eax
        ret
abs2(int):
        movl    %edi, %eax
        sarl    $31, %eax
        orl     $1, %eax
        imull   %edi, %eax
        ret
```

Код всё-таки разный. Как видите, второй вариант короче. Значит ли это, что он быстрее? Не факт. Результат зависит от реализации в процессоре, но умножение технически сложнее вычитания, поэтому выполняется чуть дольше.

Но это всё про `int`. Можете проверить и другие интересующие вас типы, просто подставив его в `typedef` в этом же инструменте. Но на вопросы "что быстрее" ответ всегда один -- **измерьте**!

Answer (score 3):

При включенном оптимизаторе будет генерироваться одинаковый код,
за исключением случаев когда `operator*` перегружен.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что второе не может быть быстрее, поскольку оно содержит больше операций, чем первое. Однако, весьма вероятно, что компилятор умный и сам подчистит оба варианта до оптимального.